# Does swift value type like String, Array, Dictionary internally contain class

Tags: swift-language

I was watching [WWDC video](https://youtu.be/vgK8jaf8nlk?t=895) and can not understand when they talk about

> Even though all of these properties are value types, internally, they
>   contain a class which is used to manage the lifetime of their internal
>   data.

Can some one share me his understanding on the above point.

Comment: Strings, arrays and dictionaries are all value types in Swift?  `#mind-blown`

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, there are no distinction like "primatives" vs "objects" like with Java. All types are either value types (Struct, Enums, Tuples) or reference types (Classes).  Many of the value types (Strings, arrays and dictionaries) implement Copy-on-Write semantics, so they're cheap to pass around if you're not aliasing and mutating them

Comment: Arrays and dictionaries are glorified classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String`, `Array`, and `Dictionary` are all structs (that get stored on the stack), but their dynamically sized "content" is stored in a buffer allocated on the stack. This buffer is part of an object, which is referenced by the struct.

Take `Array` for example, whose [source code is available on GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb) (as with the rest of the Swift programming language).
You can see that the `Array` struct contains a single member: `internal var _buffer: _Buffer`. For `Array`, this `_Buffer` type is a `typealias` for either `_ArrayBuffer<Element>` (if the Objective C runtime is being used, for faster bridging to/from `NSArray`), or `_ContiguousArrayBuffer<Element>`.

Having the `_Buffer` object wrapped up in a struct (`Array`) like this is what allows for `Array` to have copy-on-write behavior. Copies of the `Array` can be made very cheaply by simply copying the `_buffer` reference from the source array to the destination array. When a mutable operation is done, `Array` checks to see if its `_buffer` is uniquely referenced (that is, no other `Array` shares the same _buffer`).

- If it is uniquely referenced, then the mutable operation can be done directly on the `_buffer`, without the possibility of unintentionally modifying another `Array` (since there is no other `Array` sharing this `_buffer`.)
- If it is not uniquely referenced, then a copy is made, and the mutable operation is performed on the copy.